# H264QuantizationParameter and AudioVideoCaptureDevice

Tags: windows-phone-8, h.264

I'm using `IAudioVideoCaptureDeviceNative` and `StartRecordingToSinkAsync`. I need to get the bitrate lower and have been trying to set the `H264QuantizationParameter` property, but using it throws an exception. I am able to set an value before calling `StartRecordingToSinkAsync` and successfully get it using `GetProperty`, but when I call `StartRecordingToSinkAsync` *CaptureServiceClient.dll* throws an unhandled exception.

The documentation is basically non-existent on how to use this parameter or affect the bitrate, any ideas?

Comment: Same for me. Tried different combination to call before/after recording and so on.

Comment: And it seems to work fine when using the managed-side API and setting the QP inbetween OpenAsync and StartRecordingToStreamAsync, but not with StartRecordingToSinkAsync

Comment: Yes. Nokia haven't faced that issue, and the exception goes from MS stack, so the question is now transferred to MS team.

Comment: check this link: http://www.programering.com/a/MjNwQDMwATg.html